# get all data from a query select in select union mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i really confuse to get a full record from my query.

i already try the best, but i still cannot get what i want.

i am using mysql 5.5, i really dont know what to do again.

i will share my database.sql because my query join more than 5 table.

[database_schema.sql](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9OxDUZvtW22dEZZUjdNLXlCdkU)

and this is my query where i tried before.

```
select id_akun, kode_akun, nama_akun, SUM(saldo_awal) as 'SaldoAwal', SUM(debet) as 'Debet', SUM(kredit) as 'Kredit', (SUM(saldo_awal) + SUM(debet) - SUM(kredit)) as 'SaldoAkhir' from (
select a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) as saldo_awal, b.amount as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
from account a, transaksi_kas_detail b, transaksi_kas c
where a.id=b.account_id AND b.transaksi_kas_id=c.id
    AND dt='D' AND c.trx_type IN ('1', '2')
UNION
select a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', b.amount as 'kredit'
from account a, transaksi_kas_detail b, transaksi_kas c
where a.id=b.account_id AND b.transaksi_kas_id=c.id
    AND dt='K' AND c.trx_type IN ('1', '2')
UNION
select a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, b.amount as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
from account a, transaksi_kas_detail b, transaksi_kas c, kas d
where a.id=b.account_id AND b.transaksi_kas_id=c.id AND c.kas_id=d.id
    AND dt='D' AND c.trx_type IN ('3', '4')  AND d.jenis != '3'
UNION
select a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', b.amount as 'kredit'
from account a, transaksi_kas_detail b, transaksi_kas c, kas d
where a.id=b.account_id AND b.transaksi_kas_id=c.id AND c.kas_id=d.id
    AND dt='K' AND c.trx_type IN ('3', '4') AND d.jenis != '3'
UNION
select a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', b.cek_due_date as 'trx_date', (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, b.amount as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
from account a, transaksi_kas_detail b, transaksi_kas c
where a.id=b.account_id AND b.transaksi_kas_id=c.id
    AND dt='D' AND c.trx_type IN ('5', '6')
UNION
select a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', b.cek_due_date as 'trx_date', (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', b.amount as 'kredit'
from account a, transaksi_kas_detail b, transaksi_kas c
where a.id=b.account_id AND b.transaksi_kas_id=c.id
    AND dt='K' AND c.trx_type IN ('5', '6')
) fff WHERE group_account_id = '15' 
GROUP BY id_akun, kode_akun, nama_akun
ORDER BY kode_akun asc
```

after i run this query..

i will get this result.

[image]

i just get 2 record, i need to get all data by `ORDER BY kode_akun` where i get from table `account`

if table account have 10 rows, then my query must show 10 rows.

maybe someone can help me

for example like this..

[image]

Comment: Can you make an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: UNION will eleminate duplicates. Is that the issue here? If so switch to UNION ALL

Comment: @PraveenKumar i tried but my table to much, i tried to export from my database then copy the query to sqlFiddle but i dont know why the schema not create

Comment: @akiong Try to use `UNION ALL` instead of just `UNION`.

Comment: @Kickstart i tried but i stil get 2 rows like before

Comment: Your data only has 2 matching rows. The inner query brings back 3 rows, but one of those is for group_account_id of 16 hence rejected by the WHERE clause. Which rows do you think you should get?

Comment: @Kickstart you can see from table `account`, i need to show it even the field SaldoAwal, Debet, Kredit, SaldoAkhir = 0.

Comment: @Kickstart see my update image sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From you further descriptions I think what you need is to LEFT JOIN the transaksi_kas_detail AND transaksi_kas tables (and the kas table when used).

Note that you example data has the details broken down further, and not sure how you are getting that extra data.

But something like this

```
SELECTid_akun, kode_akun, nama_akun, SUM(saldo_awal) as 'SaldoAwal', SUM(debet) as 'Debet', SUM(kredit) as 'Kredit', (SUM(saldo_awal) + SUM(debet) - SUM(kredit)) as 'SaldoAkhir' 
from 
(
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) as saldo_awal, b.amount as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'D'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('1', '2')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', b.amount as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'K'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('1', '2')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, b.amount as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
    FROM account a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'D'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('3', '4')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN kas d ON c.kas_id = d.id AND d.jenis != '3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', b.amount as 'kredit'
    FROM account a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'K'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('3', '4')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN kas d ON c.kas_id = d.id AND d.jenis != '3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', b.cek_due_date as 'trx_date', (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, b.amount as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'D'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('5', '6')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', b.cek_due_date as 'trx_date', (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', b.amount as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'K'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('5', '6')
) fff 
WHERE group_account_id = '15' 
GROUP BY id_akun, kode_akun, nama_akun
ORDER BY kode_akun asc
```

EDIT - checking the dates in the ON clauses:-

```
SELECT id_akun, kode_akun, nama_akun, SUM(saldo_awal) as 'SaldoAwal', SUM(debet) as 'Debet', SUM(kredit) as 'Kredit', (SUM(saldo_awal) + SUM(debet) - SUM(kredit)) as 'SaldoAkhir' 
from 
(
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) as saldo_awal, IF(c.id IS NULL, 0, b.amount) as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'D'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('1', '2') AND c.trx_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-16 00:00:00'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', IF(c.id IS NULL, 0, b.amount) as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'K'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('1', '2') AND c.trx_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-16 00:00:00'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, IF(d.id IS NULL, 0, b.amount) as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
    FROM account a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'D'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('3', '4') AND c.trx_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-16 00:00:00'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN kas d ON c.kas_id = d.id AND d.jenis != '3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', c.trx_date, (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', IF(d.id IS NULL, 0, b.amount) as 'kredit'
    FROM account a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'K'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('3', '4') AND c.trx_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-16 00:00:00'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN kas d ON c.kas_id = d.id AND d.jenis != '3'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', b.cek_due_date as 'trx_date', (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, IF(c.id IS NULL, 0, b.amount) as 'debet', 0 as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'D' AND b.cek_due_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-16 00:00:00'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('5', '6')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.group_account_id, a.id as 'id_akun', a.code as 'kode_akun', a.name as 'nama_akun', b.cek_due_date as 'trx_date', (saldo_awal_debet - saldo_awal_kredit) saldo_awal, 0 as 'debet', IF(c.id IS NULL, 0, b.amount) as 'kredit'
    FROM account a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas_detail b ON a.id = b.account_id AND b.dt = 'K' AND b.cek_due_date BETWEEN '2016-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-11-16 00:00:00'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN transaksi_kas c ON b.transaksi_kas_id = c.id AND c.trx_type IN ('5', '6')
) fff 
WHERE group_account_id = '15' 
GROUP BY id_akun, kode_akun, nama_akun
ORDER BY kode_akun asc
```

Comment: your code already run well, but i will get different result when i add `WHERE group_account_id = 15 and trx_date >= '2016-01-01 00:00:00' and trx_date <= '2016-11-16 00:00:00' `

Comment: @akiong - The trx_date value comes from the LEFT OUTER JOINed tables, hence when no matching records they will be NULL. If you then check these values in the WHERE clause of the outer query it will exclude these records. Put the check in the ON clause of each LEFT OUTER JOIN of _transaksi_kas_detail_ . This was it will exclude them from the SUMs but keep the account details.

Comment: oh i see,,, because the record are no match with trx_date, then i am possible to get the record even trx_date  `NULL` like your query, even the record are not in `transaksi_kas_detail`, the record will show up

Comment: Put the check in the ON clause of each LEFT OUTER JOIN of transaksi_kas_detail . This was it will exclude them from the SUMs but keep the account details?

Comment: @akiong - Yes. Putting the check in the ON clause excludes it from being JOINed, but being a LEFT OUTER JOIN you still get a row, just with the columns from that table being NULL. But if you then check a value from that table in the WHERE clause it will exclude the non matched one (unless you are checking for NULL).

Comment: hi, its look like the `between` not work, for example, if i set `BETWEEN '' AND ''` the record still show up. from your code, the result mustbe the record from `2016-01-01 00:00:00` to  `2016-11-16 00:00:00`

Comment: @akiong - if I have understood your requirements then I have now fixed it.